# Restricted Cone Nat with iptables

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, nat

Can someome explain to me how do a Resctricted Cone NAT (on address and not port) with iptable. This is my configuration :

```
+---------------+           +----------------------------------+           +---------------+
|Server Test NAT|           |           NAT                    |           |Client Test NAT|
|               |           |                                  |           |               |
|               |           |                                  |           |               |
|eth0           |           |eth0                          eth1|           |eth0           |
|192.168.20.10  +-----------+192.168.20.1          192.168.10.1+-----------+192.168.20.2   |
+---------------+           +----------------------------------+           +---------------+
                            PUBLIC IP                 PRIVATE IP
```

default all Policy are in ACCEPT and after enter this rule :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

the nat type detection tells me it's a Port restricted.

So I tried to add rule :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.20.2
```

and hope this will route all incoming trafic from eth0 to the client but it does not work.

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Up that post, I want to believe someone somewhere knows the truth :)

Comment: SysAdmin please, we need you ! #super[wo]man